A movie similar to Flash Gordon
A long time ago, I saw in TV a movie but I do not remember the title. However, I remember some scenes of it. The plot of the movie is similar to Flash Gordon and most likely it was shot also in the 80s.
Now about the plot (note that I may be wrong about some of the description!). There is a city in the sky and is in danger. Something must be done within a deadline. So, the hero takes a space ship and heads to the evil guy. Upon arrival his spaceship was shot down. I remember that it crashes in a huge clock which is used for the countdown. That's it! I know these are not many details, but I hope that someone might know the title of this movie.
Many thanks in advance.  

In which context you feel its similar to flash gordon?

@AnkitSharma In many contexts I could say; same era (80s), similar visual effects, etc.

The original (Flash Gordon)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon] was in the 30s. Do you compare it to the 80s film? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(film)

@knut ... I think that's what they meant when they said, "the movie is similar to Flash Gordon and most likely it was shot also in the 80s.".

@knut The movie I am looking for is similar to the 80s version of flash gordon.

sky captain and the world of tomorrow?

Masters of the universe was made in 1987 and is quite similar to flash gordon in a way.

I'm not 100% sure, but is it possible you've seen the Buck Rogers movie from 1979? Although it's been long since I've seen that movie and can't really remember whether he's really crashing in some kind of clock; although he's definitely stealing some spaceship to fly to the bad guys and/or attack them in some way.

No it's not that. The movie am looking for has a much more lawless plot. I remember a (gold?) city in the air, then the hero travels to a desert planet and crashes into a big clock. The bad guy could be a woman! But the structure of the movie corresponds to similar 80s sci-fi (Flash Gordon, Dune, Ewoks, NOT like Star Wars). I saw this movie 20 years ago ...

Could it be Doctor Who - Aliens of London - Series 1 - BBC
YouTube preview of crash into clock tower Big Ben  




No, that doesn't fit. Also considering the crashing spaceship is the one of the bad guys.

And this is 3 decades too late. 2005.
